# IE11 User Authentication Options

Tags: authentication, internet-explorer-11, intranet

I have a strange problem with User Authentication options on IE 11. I use multiple test ids to validate a web applications in different environments. To achieve that I set up my intranet site User Authentication option to Prompt for user name and password and it works fine until IE 9. After upgrade to IE 11, I always set this and apply the setting but after 1 or 2 hours again the option will go back to  default option "automatic log on to intranet zone". Did anyone experience this problem ?

Comment: What authentication mechanism / technology are you using?

Comment: ADS, Integrated Windows Authentication